# How would i go about changing seque views if the response is 200 or not from a Alamofire request

Tags: swift, alamofire, apple-tv

So I am working on a application that logs into something I am also using alamofire. Now what I want to do is to have it go to a new view when the response code for the connection is 200 (success) and then go to a different windows when the response code is 204 (failure) I am writing this in swift 3.

Here is my current IBAction

```
 @IBAction func loginBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: isvalid200())

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "error", sender: isinvalid())
```

Now I know thats not how it is suppose to be done but it's what I have in mind. Also, here is my error handling code.

func isvalid200() {

```
    Alamofire.request("https://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml/\(user)/\(pass)")
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<200) // if error is 200
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])


       }


    func isinvalid() {


    Alamofire.request("https://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml/\(user)/\(pass)")
        .validate(statusCode: 204..<204) // if error is 204
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
    }
```

As for the error I get it is this

MyAnime[7446:265163] >'s window is not equal to 's view's window!

(without the self.dimiss but with it, it does work however it doesn't stay go to a specific windows based on the response code I.E 200 or 204.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this which switches on the statusCode

```
@IBAction func loginBtn(_ sender: Any) {
   Alamofire.request("https://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml/\(user)/\(pass)").responseJSON { [weak self] response in
      guard let strongSelf = self, let resp = response.response else { return }
    switch resp.statusCode {
       case 200:
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            strongSelf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: strongSelf)
          }
       case 204:
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            strongSelf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "error", sender: strongSelf)
          }
       default:
        //Some other status code
    }
  }
}
```

To give some explanation on what's going on lets break it down by step:

- User presses login button after entering username/password
- You make your network request to verify the credentials
- Once you receive a response you can handle whether this is a valid user or not based on the status code
- At this point, you just need to perform the necessary segue to transition to the next view controller. You would only call dismiss if you wanted to go back to the presenting view controller.

Comment: So I did that and then i put the case 200: and 204: in the middle. All it does is return default. (that's) what i told it to print in the console for the default state. For case 200 and 204 i put the self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self.isvalid200())self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: in and that did not do much

Comment: I didn't realize you had those functions in your segue, I'll update code for proper segue

Comment: So I added did the changes but now i have a ton of errors. Heres a screen shot since I can't really post the whole snippet here http://imgur.com/a/4PVWF

Comment: see updated code, I wrote an example under status code 200, you were putting isvalid200() as the sender but you already completed the check, no need to call it again. Also, that isn't something you put in sender. Sender for segues is usually just the object that is performing the segue.

Comment: you need to remove those functions from sender and remove the dismiss as well. All you need is the segue

Comment: So i just did the example and it still returns as default here is the updated code http://imgur.com/a/OfGXM

Comment: what status code are you getting back from the response? If its not 200 or 204 then it is going to go to the default case. Also, you can remove the DispatchQueue.main.async from outside of the Alamofire request. It may have been misleading how I wrote the answer, I meant just the segue not the entire request.

Comment: I'm not getting 200 or 204 back, all I am getting back in the console is Default. I also removed it from outside alamofire which didn't seem to make a difference. In case it might help here is excactly what I am using to make this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire and https://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api

Comment: if you have other response codes you want to handle, add those cases in the switch statement. If you don't then remove the 204 case and put that code in the default case. That way you either get 200 and perform the login segue or else you perform the error segue

Comment: Okay, so that works. However it's strange because that now only goes to the error seg but i know the pass I entered in the let pass = "" is correct which  is what i find strange.

Comment: That has to do with whatever backend you are using and the logic to validate the password, but it's out of the scope of this question. I recommend you check out some tutorials online to get a better grasp of the basics before you try to do too much. good luck

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit new to this type of iOS programming never really done networking stuff before. Thanks for the help!